# Splitting pandas string column into two by position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column which contains mostly strings and that I want to split into two halfs. Is there a solution to do this with one apply command only?
My current solution uses 2 applys seperately:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(["0435", "4521", "8421", "4561", 43, True, None])

part1 = data.apply(lambda x: x[:2] if isinstance(x, str) else None)
part2 = data.apply(lambda x: x[2:] if isinstance(x, str) else None)
```

Comment: The length of strings can be variable or fixed to 4 characters?

Comment: it should be 4 characters fixed as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
out = data.str.extract('(\d{2})(\d{2})') # 2 digits each group
part1 = out[0]
part2 = out[1]
```

output:

```
# part1
0     04
1     45
2     84
3     45
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN

# part2
0     35
1     21
2     21
3     61
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
```

Or with named capturing groups:

```
out = data.str.extract('(?P<part1>\d{2})(?P<part2>\d{2})')
```

output:

```
  part1 part2
0    04    35
1    45    21
2    84    21
3    45    61
4   NaN   NaN
5   NaN   NaN
6   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: with expand=True it can be done in one line.

Comment: @user2505961 I don't think so, but you if you don't mind arrays you can do `part1, part2 = data.str.extract('(\d{2})(\d{2})').T.to_numpy()`

Comment: Mhm yes you are right, weird that expand=True it doesn't work here.